# How to use DurationFormatUtils class to get the result in desired format?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have a timestamp in milliseconds and I want to convert this to hours, minutes, seconds but in the below format only:

```
20hrs 10mins 50sec
```

I wanted to come up with some better format of reading the data so decided to use above one. I am using `DurationFormatUtils` class from Apache Commons to give me result in this format `HH:mm:ss,SSS` as of now:

```
DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(durationForStep, "HH:mm:ss,SSS")
```

Is there any way I can use `DurationFormatUtils` class only yo get the result in my above format? If not then I think manual work will be the only other option I guess?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't used this, but according to the javadoc shouldn't you be able to just do the following?

```
DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(durationForStep, "HH'hrs' mm'mins' ss'sec'");
```